# SFTP modules in Node to download and delete files

Tags: node.js, sftp

my task is (or better, should be) simple: to fetch the content of a directory in SFTP from a Node application, then download all the files in there and finally delete them remotely.

Now, I've checked different modules. Very clean, in my opinion, is ssh2-sftp-client. I can use it like this:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();

sftp.connect({
    host: myhost,
    port: '22',
    username: myusername,
    password: mypassword
}).then(() => {
    return sftp.list('/path/to/my/files');
}).then((data) => {

    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        sftp.get('/path/to/my/files/'+data[i].name); 
        }   
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'catch error');
});
```

I can list all files and see the resulting jSon in console, but the .get command seems to do nothing and I have no idea what is wrong. From the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client) you can get files simply like I'm doing. But:

1) it doesn't seem to work
2) how can I debug what's going on?
3) if I have no chance to choose the local directory, will these files most probably be downloaded where the js is launched by node, right?

So, how could I get the files actually downloaded and possibly deleted remotely if they were successfully downloaded with this module (or others if any)?

Thanks,
Fabio

Comment: `sftp.get('/path/to/my/files/'+data[i].name)` returns a stream. You have to handle that stream and save it as a file in your local machine.

Comment: Thanks, could you address me to the sftp command I could use to finish this task, that is to handle the stream? Even if the module does not implement it, I could use the ssh2 base module methods.

Comment: Okay... I can help you. Do you want to save the stream as a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sftp.get()` returns a Promise that returns a stream, so if you want to save the stream to disk, you will need to pipe it. For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// ...

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const remoteFilename = '/path/to/remote/files/' + data[i].name;
  const localFilename = '/path/to/local/files/' + data[i].name;
  sftp.get(remoteFilename).then((stream) => {
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilename));
  });
}
```

Also, it appears that `ssh2-sftp-client` is not using the latest version branch of the `ssh2` module (v0.5.x as of this writing), so keep that in mind if you run into issues.

Comment: It gives me: TypeError: sftp.get(...).pipe is not a function. However i understood your solution and I'll investigate further. Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok, so the module's documentation is wrong/misleading. It actually returns a *Promise* that returns a stream (rather odd since there is nothing async about getting a file stream).

Comment: I see, yes, sometimes documentations are really poor. And it's a pity. I am almost there, although the get and pipe breaks the for loop and only the last file is actually downloaded.

'for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
  var remoteFilename = '/path/to/my/files/' + data[i].name;
  var localFilename = data[i].name;
  sftp.get(remoteFilename).then((stream) => {
      console.log(i);
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilename));
  });
}'

where the first console prints 0,1,2,3,4,5, while the second prints 6 times 5.

Comment: it is all ok now! I had to follow your advice and declare the paths as const and not var.

Comment: @FabioRicci could you post your final code? I'm running into a similar issue and would love a jumping off point.

Comment: @mscdex  The above solution gives me TypeError: sftp.get(...).pipe error. I have declared  both remoteFilename and localFilename as const. Still running to this issue.

Comment: @FabioRicci  can you post your solution for this error?

Comment: @mscdex stream is not a function ....(node:15448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: stream.pipe is not a function
    at D:\Work\test\test\index.js:96:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Answer (score 1):

```
sftp.get(remoteFileNameWithPath, true).then(stream => {
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath)).on('close', () => console.log('completely passed file'))
})
```

the get method returns a promise with a stream result, so, In order to save this you need to pipe to a writeStream
Check docs on nodejs: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Answer (score 0):

Download and save file using get() method

```js
sftp.get(remote_file_path, local_file_path).then((stream) => {
    console.log('File download Success')
});
```

It requires two param: src and dest file path

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what happens but when I ran a code like this it only download one file.

```
for (var i = fileList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  remoteFilename = process.env.FTP_DEFAULT_DIR + '/' + fileList[i].name
  localFilename = fileList[i].name

  sftp.get(remoteFilename).then((stream) => {
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilename));
    console.log(stream);
    console.log('processing: ', remoteFilename);
  }).catch((err)=> {
    console.log(err)
  });
}
```